# How to copy all files with extension type to a folder?

Tags: arcpy, copy

What is the best way to go about this? I'm able to do it with a single file as below, but what if I would like to copy all files with .txt to a folder, and all files with .docx to another folder. I tried changing in_data to just .txt but this did not work.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\X220\Documents"

# Set local variables
in_data =  "test.txt"
out_data = "C:\Users\X220\Documents\output\Copy.docx"

# Execute Copy
arcpy.Copy_management(in_data, out_data)
```

Comment: Usually when multiple copying, /*.extension used. Did you try in_data =  "*.txt"? and out_data is a directory

Comment: Tried that and got: ERROR 000732: Input Data: Dataset *.txt does not exist or is not supported

Comment: maybe this helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/296184/8129993

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 has been retired for a long time. The Python that shipped with it is ancient. If you are using a modern release, please [Edit] the question body *and* tag.

Comment: `import os, glob` then `for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(in_path, '*.txt'))):`

Comment: If ListFiles was available in ArcPy at 10.0 then doing what you want should be possible without using os or glob, which I think would make this on-topic for GIS. If ListFiles were part of your code snippet then I would probably vote to re-open your question.